# HOW to create .json file with specific data?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have this .json file in nodejs:

```
{
  html_attributions: [],
  results: [
    {
      business_status: 'OPERATIONAL',
      geometry: [Object],
      icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png',
      id: '8e980ad0c819c33cdb1cea31e72d654ca61a7065',
      name: 'Cruise Bar',
      opening_hours: [Object],
      photos: [Array],
      place_id: 'ChIJi6C1MxquEmsR9-c-3O48ykI',
      plus_code: [Object],
      price_level: 2,
      rating: 4,
      reference: 'ChIJi6C1MxquEmsR9-c-3O48ykI',
      scope: 'GOOGLE',
      types: [Array],
      user_ratings_total: 1009,
      vicinity: 'Level 1, 2 and 3, Overseas Passenger Terminal, Circular Quay W, The Rocks'
    },
    {
      business_status: 'OPERATIONAL',
      geometry: [Object],
      icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png',
      id: 'f1e044040bd03ff06e19de4798b52dd926855281',
      name: 'Sydney Harbour Dinner Cruises',
      opening_hours: [Object],
      photos: [Array],
      place_id: 'ChIJM1mOVTS6EmsRKaDzrTsgids',
      plus_code: [Object],
      rating: 4.3,
      reference: 'ChIJM1mOVTS6EmsRKaDzrTsgids',
      scope: 'GOOGLE',
      types: [Array],
      user_ratings_total: 3,
      vicinity: '32 The Promenade, Sydney'
    },
    {
      business_status: 'OPERATIONAL',
      geometry: [Object],
      icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png',
      id: '6facf611e56f3d6f232a24e60d9392759bbd43fa',
      name: 'Junk Lounge',
      opening_hours: [Object],
      photos: [Array],
      place_id: 'ChIJq9W3HZOvEmsRYtKNTRmq34M',
      plus_code: [Object],
      price_level: 2,
      rating: 4.1,
      reference: 'ChIJq9W3HZOvEmsRYtKNTRmq34M',
      scope: 'GOOGLE',
      types: [Array],
      user_ratings_total: 36,
      vicinity: 'Level 2, Overseas Passenger Terminal, Circular Quay W, The Rocks'
    }
  ],
  status: 'OK'
}
```

It's longer but I didn't put it here.

## I want to create another JSON with each name, vicinity, and photos from results.

because I search for a location and I need places like restaurants. How you can see in the code I attached here I have: name like 'Cruise Bar', 'Sydney Harbour Dinner Cruises' and 'Junk Lounge'

Can you suggest me how to do that?
I don't know how to check the end of json.
I need a FOR to put all of this information in a variable?

like var result =
{ "name" : json.results,.... }

Comment: use ```fs``` to write a file which contains ```JSON.stringify(json.result[0],null,2)```

Comment: what do you mean by "to check the end of json"?
Do you want to extract specific keys from all elements of `results[]` or just from `results[0]`

Comment: I need all results[] , because I search for a location and I need places like restaurants. How you can see in the code I attached here I have: name like  'Cruise Bar', 'Sydney Harbour Dinner Cruises' and 'Junk Lounge'

Answer (score 0):

try this, `original` is your given object.
You'll get an array of object containing name, vicinity and photos.

```
const new_array = original.results.map((result) =>{
    return {name : result.name,
            vicinity : result.vicinity,
            photos : result.photos }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Follow the below steps:

1. Convert this into a CSV File and then
2. go to the following Webpage: [convertcsv](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) to convert csv to json